# Nginx Unit in relation to PSGI/Dancer stack

Tags: perl, nginx, dancer, plack, psgi

According to [Nginx goes beyond its server roots and launches its application platform](http://techcrunch.com/2017/09/06/nginx-launches-its-application-platform/)

> ..Unit is a modern application server for applications written in
>   PHP, Python and Go (with support for node.js, Java, Ruby Perl and
>   others following soon), that run in dynamic environments.

Where does Unit fit in a ngnix->PSGI->Starman->Dancer stack? 
which part does it replace or adds to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example nginx and Starman are comunicating using HTTP, not PSGI (because PSGI is interface, and HTTP is protocol). So stack will look like `Unit->Dancer`. In case if you need some nginx features your can use it in front of Unit: `nginx->Unit->Dancer`.